# Apply css only for linux chrome but not for windows chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux, debian

Is the any way to apply css only for the linux chrome.
Currently i am using the following code

```
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { //css code  }
```

but the problem here is it is applying for both linux and windows chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need to?

Comment: I am using font family which is not compatible to linux. so my client wants seperate fonts in windows chrome and linux chrome.

Comment: I dont think you can detect the Operation System using css, but will be interested in hearing if u find a way. However this can be done using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of (and I don't like it) is to use JavaScript (as you tagged `javascript` on the question) to detect "Linux" in the user agent string and then add a class to `body` or similar to activate the Linux-only style; or the converse, add the class only when *not* using Linux. (But I'd lean toward the former.)

```
if (/\blinux\b/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.body.className += " linux";
}
```

or

```
if (!/\blinux\b/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    document.body.className += " not-linux";
}
```

Then use the `.linux` or `.not-linux` ancestors when defining the relevant styles.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a platform detection library like Platform here https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/ and then when the document loads add the platform name as a class to the html body tag. Then you could add a css rule to look for this class.

If you are using jquery you could do this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').addClass(platform.name)

});
```

Then in the css you could do this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    .linux .some-element-class{

        background: blue;

    }

}
```

This example that the value from platform.name was "linux"

Comment: sorry it is adding the class in both linux and windows.

Comment: Yes, this would add the class name for any OS. If you only wanted to add a class for one OS then you could do a check like @T.J. Crowder suggests.